# How can I limit access to a single static page to authenticated users in Yii?

Tags: yii

How can I create a single static page in Yii that only logged in users can view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is good documentation on how to enable Yii's [access control filter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#access-control-filter) for a controller action on the guide. You will have to make a controller action that displays a static view, and limit access to that action based on the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for this; I've learned quite a bit looking through your link and the fundamental's section: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller

Comment: @Bob: Happy to help. Do read as much of that guide as you can assimilate (I did it in parts), it's very useful.

Answer (score 3):

You must create an action inside your controller, say `public function actionStaticpage()`, and:

This action will handle the view rendering of the static contents you may want to show, i.e. some instructions/faq for logged users, a tutorial, etc. For instance:

```
public function actionStaticpage() {
    $this->render('faq');
}
```

You'll now have to specify that this action is intended to be viewable **only** for logged users. You may accomplish this by using your Controller's function `accessRules()`. It would be something like this:

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform these actions
            'actions'=>array('staticpage'),
            'users'=>array('@'),
        ),
    );
}
```

And that's it. You can also make your Staticpage a little more dynamic, for example by having a parameter inside it, specifying which static content you want to display `public function actionStaticpage($page)` and then using `switch` or `if` statements to correctly display contents.